# Do I always need to use "als ob" in subjunctive form?

Tags: usage, subjunctive

I don't know where found this sentence on the net, but a friend of me says that **als ob** can be used in subjunctive only. I'm sure I extracted this sentence from a German passage or text. Can't **als ob** be used here?

> Manchmal habe ich das Gefühl, als ob wir uns schon sehr lange kennen.

Comment: In fact, this sentence is using the subjunctive (Konjunktiv I), because the subclause is an Irrealis.

Comment: Don't overthink this. The sentence is fine.

Comment: Depends on whether you want your sentences to be 95% or 100% correct. Indicative is not "textbook-correct", but acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your example is the 1st person plural Konjunktiv I of *kennen* is indistinguishable from Indikativ.

> So als ob wir einander schon ewig kennen. *(Konjunktiv I)*
>
> So als ob wir einander schon ewig kennen. *(Indikativ)*

Better use the simplified **würde** Konjunktiv I in such cases:

> So als ob wir einander schon ewig kennen würden.

There is no such problem with the 3rd person singular of *kennen*:

> So als ob er mich schon ewig kenne. *(Konjunktiv I)*
>
> So als ob er mich schon ewig kennt. *(Indikativ)*

**BUT** in speech people seem to forget about the Konjunktiv I and its uses and use Indikativ instead. So, you can be as sloppy as German native speakers and do the same unless your goal is writing essays for the general public.

Comment: "So als ob er mich schon ewig kenne" sounds rather strange, I would also go with "So als ob er mich schon ewig kennen wuerde" here...